# Pagination with cache in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Can anyone help me? I use redis cache. But I see same results on every pages when I use pagination. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Probably not without seeing some code/screenshots of the issue

Comment: Can you add some of your code?

Comment: https://laravel.io/forum/09-15-2015-redis-and-pagination - does this help?

Comment: this is code example  https://laravel.io/bin/wJP54

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should cache your results per page, with a key that is the current page.

```
$currentPage = request()->get('page',1);

$category = Cache::remember('sellcategory-' . $currentPage, 10, function(){
    return DB::table('elans')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->where(['derc' => 1,'elaninnovu' => 'Satılır'])->paginate(10);
});
```

Comment: How to remove (forget / flush) keys like these on newly added record without Cache Tags (because of 'file' cache driver), please? Thanks.

Comment: @JakubAdamec If you don;t want to use the Redis cache driver for the tags, you can loop the number of pages the records have and just delete all the keys.

Answer (score 5):

This solution to cache and clear pagination caches.

How to cache:

```
$page = request()->get('page', 1);
$limit = request()->get('limit', 10);

$users = Cache::remember('admin' . $page, 10, function() use ($limit){
    return DB::table('users')->paginate($limit);
});
```

You can use a loop to check the prefix and delete them like this.

```
public static function forgetCaches($prefix)
{
    // Increase loop if you need, the loop will stop when key not found
    for ($i=1; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        $key = $prefix . $i;
        if (Cache::has($key)) {
            Cache::forget($key);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Clear caches:

```
// Clear caches:
forgetCaches('admin');
```

Comment: impressive, keep going